# Django. Как автоматизировать выполнение задач через определенный промежуток времени

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Собственно вопрос состоит в том, чтобы определенный скрипт(ф-я) производит обновления данных для сайта. Где прописывать данный скрипт(ф-ю) и какие есть варианты решения задачи?

Comment: cron, celery, ...

Comment: Это же питон, можно хоть самому запустить отдельный процесс, который будет обновлять, что нужно.

Comment: @МистерФикс не подскажите - как это реализовать?

Comment: Просто пишете скрипт, который крутится в бесконечном цикле и  каждые пять минут(или сколько вам надо) обновляет те данные, которые вам нужны.

Comment: Если в качестве web сервера используется uwsgi, то в нем есть функциональность для запуска периодических задач

Answer (score 1):

Ну например так:

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(300)  # скрипт отдыхает 5мин
    print("данные сайта обновились")
```

Ну если данные сайта долго обновляются, то можно так:

```
import time
import threading

while True:
    time.sleep(300)
    thread = threading.Thread( #  создание отдельного потока
        target=print, args=("данные сайта обновились", ))
    thread.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю суть вопроса, то вам нужна работа с Django ORM по определенному интервалу.

Разбор идеи по шагам.

**1. Python скрипт для автоматизации**

Как уже говорилось выше вы можете создать отдельный поток

```
import time
import threading

delay = 86400 #время между вызовами функции в секундах, в данном примере - сутки

def do_something(): #вызываемая в отдельном потоке функция в ней и производим действия из следующего шага
    pass

while True:
    time.sleep(delay)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=do_something)
    thread.start()
```

**2. Изменение модели**

*Вот ответ на этот вопрос:* https://stackoverflow.com/a/18760222/5004246