# текущая цена акций индекса Dow Jones через телеграмм бота

Tags: python, веб-сервер, telegram-bot, python-3.5, screenshots

Я создаю  телеграмм бота , который присылает текущую цену акций Dow Jones. Процесс работает таким образом, что снимает скрин из Google, а затем сжимает  его и отправляет его как сообщение. Но что, если 2 или более пользователей будут запускать эту команду одновременно? Как избежать коллизий? Мне нужны потоки? Могу ли я сделать этот процесс быстрее?

```
@bot.message_handler(func = lambda message: 'Dow Jones'in message.text)

def repeat_all_messages222(message):
    url='https://www.google.com/search?q=dow+jones+current+price&oq=dow+jones+current+price&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'
    adr='/home/weblanss/mysite/dowJones/ss.png'

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'please wait your request is being processed')

    size=(120 ,190,760, 640 )
    ecran(url,size,adr)
    w2=open(adr,'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id,w2)


def ecran (url,size,adr):
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    display.start()

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    browser.implicitly_wait(15)


    browser.get(url)
    browser.implicitly_wait(15)
    browser.save_screenshot(adr)

    browser.quit()
    img = Image.open(adr)
    crop_rectangle = size
    cropped_img = img.crop(crop_rectangle)

    cropped_img.save(adr)
    display.stop()
```

Я использую сервер pythonanywhere. python 3.5 или, возможно, есть другие простые способы получить текущую цену? Для меня изображение - хороший вариант т.к. оно с графиком , но могу получать цену как целые числа. API Yahoo, например, не показывает текущую цену индекса Dow Jones. Подскажите, какие есть еще варианты.

Comment: На мой взгляд, передавать число предпочтительнее, т.к. его можно будет обработать на стороне клиента при необходимости (провести вычисления, построить график). Плюс меньше потребление трафика, чем картинка. Если вдруг не найдете нужное API, то я бы тянул с любого надежного сайта (например rbc), используя парсинг html.

Comment: делайте один скрин раз в секунду (например) и отправляйте его в ответ на все запросы, полученные в течении этой секунды

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам действительно стоит использовать [API](https://geektimes.ru/post/217547/) вместо скриншота?
Как я вижу, порядок действий таков:

1. В отдельном потоке (вот самый простой пример [выполнения задачи через определенный промежуток времени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/615266/183429)) получаем данные через выбранный вами API.
2. Держим эти данные в памяти (просто храните в переменной, остальное Python делает за Вас) обновляя эти данные каждую секунду.
3. Возвращаем всем запросам данные из переменной. Если вам очень нужна красота и вы все же предпочитаете возвращать пользователю картинку вы можете [генерировать свое собственное изображение](https://habrahabr.ru/post/49361/) (с вашим дизайном).

[Более подробно развернутое сравнение разных финансовых API (англ.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040954/alternative-to-google-finance-api)